# WebGrid Custom Async Calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have a WebGrid declared as below:

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: Model.RowsPerPage, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "WebGrid");
```

I noticed where ever there is a `data-swhglnk="true"` attribute in a `<a></a>` e.g. Columns for sorting, the asynchronous behavior occurs and my WebGrid is updated.

***I want to tap into the same behavior without much change to update the WebGrid on my custom interaction like user passed a filter string from a textbox or changed the number of rows per page from a dropdown, etc.*** 

I also noticed that a big number is sent to the server like `http://localhost:6066/Grid?sort=ID&sortdir=ASC&__swhg=1388556493888` when there is `data-swhglnk="true"`.

Can someone please shed some light on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I had to resort to doing my own custom ajax call and replacing the div with returned data. I could not tap into WebGrid's async behavior with my own callbacks.